# C# ListView Appears Blank with Groups

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

In VS2005, using C#, I have a Forms application with a ListView. I can added items to the listview just fine. However, as soon as I try to sort those items into groups, they don't appear. I know that groups don't appear when they're empty, but I've confirmed these groups are *not* empty.  Also, I *am* setting listView.ShowGroups = true.  If I add items to one of the groups, but not the second, the "Default" group does show up...it's just the groups I've added that don't appear!

Here's the code I'm using:

```
this.listView.View = View.Details;
this.listView.Columns.Add("Column1");
this.listView.Columns[0].Width = this.listView.Width - 20;
this.listView.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
this.listView.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("A"));
this.listView.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("D"));


foreach(item i in Class.Items)
{
    if (i.Type == Type.A)
        this.listView.Groups[0].Items.Add(i.Name);
    else
        this.listView.Groups[1].Items.Add(i.Name);
}
this.listView.ShowGroups = true;
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why my groups don't show up? Here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the humorous screen shot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not add items to the group, but rather adding items to the list view, and for each item set its `Group` property to the desired group.

You can see an example in this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: That did it. Huh, that intuitively doesn't feel like a natural way of doing it to me, but...apparently it's what made sense to MSFT at the time.  Thanks!

Comment: @JToland: I assume that one possible reason is so that you can move items easily from one group to another at run-time without having to recreate the item. But more likely, it's also related to the fact that groups are not displayed under versions of Windows prior to XP, so the items need to be owned by the `ListView` itself in order to be displayed at all in that environment.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, you're probably right. Anyway, I agree with JToland that's not really intuitive :D

Comment: Crappy api, at least the Group Add should throw an Exception.

Answer (score 7):

If items are added to the listview while the `ShowGroups` value is set to false and then the `ShowGroups` property is later set to true, the listbox will appear blank while showing groups (but with content when `ShowGroups` is false).

`ShowGroups` needs to be true when building the list.

The timing is also important. The listbox needs to be rendered before the `ShowGroups` property is set to false. I set it in my dialog shown event.

I discovered this while working in .Net 4.0.

Comment: Wow, thank you! not very intuitive!  Can be expected that changing       ShowGroups will throw a listview repainting...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
listView.Groups[0].Items.Add(listView.Items.Add("Item 1"));
```